# c++ Object.method() = "string"

Tags: c++, string, object, methods, equals

I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
I have to make a method like this:
v
vI have to make a method like this:
 `//os1.miasto()="Zmieniono miasto osoby 1.";`

we have method that equals to string. How to implement this method?**

````
#ifdef _WIN32
 #include <windows.h>
#endif // _WIN32 and _WIN64 too
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class adres{
 string mia, ul;
 int nr;
public:

 adres(): mia(""),ul(""),nr(0){}                    

 adres(const string& a1, const string& a2, int a3): mia(a1), ul(a2), nr(a3){}

 ostream& view(ostream& out) const{
   return out << mia << ", " << ul << ", " << nr << '\n';
 }

 friend 
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const adres& r);

};
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const adres& r){
 return r.view(out);  
}

class osoba{
 string im;
 int wi;
 adres* adr;
public:

 osoba():im(""),wi(0),adr(0){}
 
 osoba(const string& a1, int a2, const adres& a3):im(a1), wi(a2), adr(new adres(a3)){}


 osoba(const osoba& a1): im(a1.im), wi(a1.wi),  // konstruktor kopiujacy
       adr(new adres(*a1.adr)) {}


 osoba& operator=(const osoba& a1){     // operator przypisania kopiujacego
   if(this != &a1){                     // jeżeli adresy obiektów są różne
       delete adr;
       im = a1.im;
       wi = a1.wi;
       adr = new adres(*a1.adr);
   }
   return *this;                       // Porównywane obiekty są takie same, zwraca referencje do samego siebie
 }

 ~osoba(){ delete adr; }

 // resztę dopisz sam - potrzebne są metody miasto() w tej klasie

  

 friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const osoba& r);

};
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const osoba& r){

 return out << r.im << ", " << r.wi << ", " << *r.adr ;
}

int main(){
 #ifdef _WIN32
   SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); 
 #endif



adres* wsk = new adres("Częstochowa", "Dąbrowskiego", 73);

cout <<  wsk << '\n';
cout << *wsk << '\n';

adres a1(*wsk);
delete wsk;
wsk=nullptr;            // Należy uruchomić jako  g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic Zadanie2.cpp -o Zadanie2.exe

const adres* wsk1 = new adres("Łódź", "Piotrkowska", 33);

cout << a1 << '\n';
cout << *wsk1 << '\n';

adres a2;
cout << a2 << '\n';
a2 = a1;
cout << a2 << '\n';

osoba os1("Ala", 25, *wsk1);
delete wsk1;

cout << os1 << '\n';
osoba os2(os1);


//os1.miasto()="Zmieniono miasto osoby 1.";
cout << os2 << '\n';

//osoba os3;
//cout << os3 << '\n';
//os3 = os2;

//os1.miasto()="Drugi raz zmieniono miasto osoby 1.";
//cout << os3 << '\n'; 
} ```
````

Comment: How did the code you *saw* this in implement this method?

Comment: Open your C++ textbook and read about references.

Answer (score 1):

The `city()` member function just has to return a non-`const` reference any object with an `operator=(const char*)`, or some other type that can be constructed therefrom.  For instance...

```
struct Person {
    std::string city_;
    std::string& city() { return city_; }
    ...whatever else...
};
```

This is not normally considered good interface design!

Comment: I disagree. This is how `std` designs many of it's interfaces

Comment: @Caleth: can you please support your assertion with some examples of the `std` functions you're thinking of?  (IMHO, `at()`, `operator[](size_t)`, and `get<T>()`  support for chaining aren't similar to the above as they're idiomatic indexed access to expose member data, and `return *this;` for chaining (e.g. `operator<<`) doesn't break encapsulation so is distinct from the above.  I've no doubt there are other returns-by-non-const-reference, but haven't thought of any genuinely similar).

Answer (score 1):

If `city()` is a function that returns a *reference* to a member function of the class of which `person1` is instance, then

```
person1.city() = "City of person 1 changed";
```

is a way of modifying that member via that returned reference.

Unless used carefully it can circumvent encapsulation. But it is occasionally useful: (i) The C++ standard library adopts this where function names are standardised but member variables are not (apart from a couple of exceptions - e.g. `std::cout` - C++ standard library member variables are all hidden as implementation details using reserved identifiers), (ii) `city()` could be polymorphic.

Comment: *returns a reference* likely, but not necessarily.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Yes there are other cases, e.g. city() could return an object that defines an assignment operator to `const char*` that has a side effect. I took care not to write "if and only if".

Comment: Exactly. The question lacks necessary details to answer it decisively.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: For me there a sufficient clue in the content of the `const char[]` literal. But if you find the question incomplete, vote it down / vote to close / comment. If you find this answer not useful, then downvote it.

Comment: My initial comment was mostly for future readers than you honestly. I don't doubt you know what you're talking about. The question is closed for better or for worse anyway.